# ionic command not found when trying to ionic serve

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

For some reason my ionic stopped working. I try ionic serve on my project and get the error bash: ionic: command not found. My OS is windows 10, any ideas? It was working just fine yesterday , and I haven't touched my pc.

Comment: What happened when you typed `ionic info`?

Comment: $ ionic info
bash: ionic: command not found

Comment: Are you in the `root` folder?

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall the latest ionic and please check your enviroment paths in windows, and see wether node C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin is there.

> npm install -g ionic@latest

Comment: Only nodejs\npm\node_modules\bin. And i have another node_modules at C:\usr\local\node_modules\ionic. Is that the problem? how should it be? btw i did the install already.

Comment: I also tried npm uninstall -g ionic , npm cache clean , npm install -g ionic@latest. =/ same error

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled ionic and npm decided to put ionic into \ionic\bin\ionic

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g ionic cordova
C:\Users\nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> 
C:\Users\nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
C:\Users\nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> 
C:\Users\nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic
    + ionic@5.2.7
    + cordova@9.0.0
added 681 packages from 391 contributors in 29.54s
```

I've added these folders to my path, but I assume it's not supposed to work like this...

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;
C:\Users\nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin;
C:\Users\nick\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue as well.
 Pls try to reinstall the node.js and remember to set the install directory to **C:\Users\{{YourUsername}}**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I added C:\Program Files\nodejs to my Environment-Variables and now it works.